# Glassfish 4.1.1, domain installed as a service does not restart as a service

Tags: windows, service, glassfish

I got a Glassfish 4.1.1 copy with two domains on Win2012R2 (no clusters, no instances). I've set a windows service for each of those.

Both services run regularly up until the moment when I restart either or both of them thru their admin web console (*server (Admin Server) -> Restart*). The following happens:

- The domain-related service stops, but does not start again,
- The allegedly stopped domain is perfectly functional (deployed apps and admin console are there) (!!!),
- When I try to start the win service manually, I get `Error 1067` (GF reports "something" is already listening on required ports and that's the domain itself that is now, somehow, **NOT** run as a service!),
- I can start the service again only after I've stopped the domain thru *server (Admin Server) -> Stop*.

Why did I mention two domains? **Because this does not happen when I have just one domain with its' service.**

Domains do not share ports, only things in common are the JDK/JRE and general GF files.

Is this a bug in Glassfish or did I set something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing, I realized what was going on:

- Glassfish is definitively capable of restarting its' own Windows service,
- The thing that was happening is it takes GF a few seconds do this on its' own,
- But, before GF domain could restart as a service, I clicked the URL to return to admin console, every time. That forced it to run as an ordinary executable.

It does seem like the restart happens faster with just one win service, but I won't claim that as an absolute truth without more testing, for which I have no time now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation, rather than a bug. The problem is that GlassFish has no way to tell whether or not it is running as a service (and, if it is, what the name of that service would be).

The restart command means that GlassFish is restarting itself, so Windows detects that the process it started has been terminated and shows the service as stopped, but GlassFish spawns a new JVM itself. It has no capability to tell Windows to start the service again.

Essentially, the behaviour you are seeing is expected.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but this part has me confused: "GlassFish spawns a new JVM itself. It has no capability to tell Windows to start the service again." Then, how does GF have that capability when there's just one service? Restart does restart the service just fine in that situation.